# How to perfectly center a circle that changes based on the users input

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm doing a circumference/area calculator. The users input is the radius of the circle, and I'm setting this value so it can be the width and height when creating the visualization of a circle, but the drawing is not centered and it keeps changing position. I suspect this is because the circle is not the same width as it is changing based on the user so it does not stay centered.

**The Input**

```
<input type="number" id="radius" placeholder="Enter the radius">
```

**The div of the circle**

```
<div class="circles">
      <span class="circle"></span>
    </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
      const $radius = $("#radius").val();
      const $diameter = ($radius * 2);
      const $radioPick = $("input[name='calculation']:checked").val();
      const $converted = ($radius * 37.795275591);


$('.circle').css({
          height: $converted,
          width: $converted
        });
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
  border: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) solid;
  background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.circle').hide();

  $('#radius').on('keyup', () => {
    const $radius = $("#radius").val();
    const $diameter = ($radius * 2);
    const $radioPick = $("input[name='calculation']:checked").val();
    const $converted = ($radius * 37.795275591);

    if ($radius < 0) {
      $('#error').text('Please input positive integers');
      return false;

    } else if ($radioPick === "area") {
      const $acalc = ($radius * $radius * Math.PI).toPrecision(6);
      $('#feedback').text('Area = ' + $acalc + ' cm\u00B2');
      $('#diameter').text('Diameter = ' + $diameter + ' cm\u00B2');
      $('.circle').css({
        height: $converted,
        width: $converted
      });
      $('.circle').fadeIn(300);
      $('#error').hide();

    } else if ($radioPick === "circuference") {
      const $circalc = (2 * Math.PI * $radius).toPrecision(6);
      $('#feedback').text('Circunference = ' + $circalc);
      $('#diameter').text('Diameter = ' + $diameter);
      $('.circle').css({
        height: (2 * $converted),
        width: (2 * $converted)
      });
      $('.circle').fadeIn(300);
      $('#error').hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title h1 {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 50px;
  /* top: 5%; */
  /* left: 35%; */
}

#radius {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#bttn {
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 0.5px black solid;
}

.calculations {}

input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"],
label {}

.answer {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.answer p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.circle {
  border: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) solid;
  background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

#error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Circles Calculator</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="calculations">
    <input type="radio" name="calculation" value="area"><label> Area</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="calculation" value="circuference"><label> Circuference</label><br />
    <input type="number" id="radius" placeholder="Enter the radius">
    <input type="button" id="bttn" name="calculate" value="Calculate">
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p id="feedback"></p>
    <p id="diameter"></p>
    <p id="error"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="circles">
    <span class="circle"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is : Make a circle that stays perfectly centered in the screen / Changes size, based on input but doesn't move

Comment: Make a working snippet of your code (hit CTRL-M while editing or click the button)

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mvcaskh9/

Comment: just add `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)` to `.circle` class. https://jsfiddle.net/mvcaskh9/2/

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara, your method works thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The trick is a bit of CSS Magic. You need to dynamically adjust your `top` and `left` for the element with `circle` class like you are doing with `width` and `height`. We make use of CSS3 `calc()` property. Consider, when calculating Area:

```
$('.circle').css({
  height: $converted,
  width: $converted,
  top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted/2) + "px)",
  left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted/2) + "px)"
});
```

Or Circumference:

```
$('.circle').css({
  height: $converted,
  width: $converted,
  top: "calc(50% - " + $converted + "px)",
  left: "calc(50% - " + $converted + "px)"
});
```

Now the `top` and `left` will get calculated for 50% - the radius of the circle, keeping it's center in the center of the page.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/cgLfz1ro/

There are a few minor other changes you may consider too. Like checking to make sure the user has selected Area or Circumference and generating an error if they have not.

Answer (score 0):

I took liberty with the code to show errors when no type was selected.
I also added a change event handler for the number input since keyup would not handler cases on number  I also set a `min='0'` to avoid some errors.
I added and event handler for the radio change so if they get an error on that, fix it by a choice, it fires the calculation.
**CSS has an update for the actual question.**

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type='radio'][name='calculation']").on('change', function() {
    $('#error').hide();
    $('#radius').trigger('change');
  });
  $('#radius').on('keyup change', function() {
    //$('#error').hide();
    const $radius = $(this).val();
    const $diameter = ($radius * 2);
    const $radio = $("input[type='radio'][name='calculation']:checked");
    const $radioPick = $radio.val();
    const $converted = ($radius * 37.795275591);
    var fbtext = "";
    var diText = "";
    var circCss = 0;

    if ($radius < 0) {
      $('#error').text('Please input positive integers').show();
      return false;
    }
    if (!$radio.length > 0) {
      //console.log('radiobad');
      $('#error').text('Please choose a type').show();
      return false;
    }
    if ($radioPick === "area") {
      const $acalc = ($radius * $radius * Math.PI).toPrecision(6);
      fbtext = 'Area = ' + $acalc + ' cm\u00B2';
      diText = 'Diameter = ' + $diameter + ' cm\u00B2';
      circCss = $converted;
    }
    if ($radioPick === "circuference") {
      const $circalc = (2 * Math.PI * $radius).toPrecision(6);
      fbtext = 'Circunference = ' + $circalc;
      diText = 'Diameter = ' + $diameter;
      circCss = (2 * $converted);
    }
    $('.circle').css({
      height: circCss,
      width: circCss
    });
    $('#feedback').text(fbtext);
    $('#diameter').text(diText);
    $('.circle').fadeIn(300);
    $('#error').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title h1 {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 50px;
  /* top: 5%; */
  /* left: 35%; */
}

#radius {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#bttn {
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 0.5px black solid;
}

.calculations {}

input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"],
label {}

.answer {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.answer p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.circle {
  border: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) solid;
  background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Circles Calculator</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="calculations">
    <input type="radio" name="calculation" value="area"><label>Area</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="calculation" value="circuference"><label>Circuference</label><br />
    <input type="number" min="0" id="radius" placeholder="Enter the radius">
    <input type="button" id="bttn" name="calculate" value="Calculate">
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p id="feedback"></p>
    <p id="diameter"></p>
    <p id="error"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="circles">
    <span class="circle"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```